# google script scrape parser. Как вывести значение следующего одинакового тега?

Tags: google-apps-script

Есть скрипт https://script.google.com/d/1Mc8BthYthXx6CoIz90-JiSzSafVnT6U3t0z_W3hLTAX5ek4w0G_EIrNw/edit?usp=drive_web, который используется в качестве библиотеки. Пытаюсь получить значение из второго по счету тега [font size="2"] путем добавления [1], но он не переходит к следующему значению. Как получить следующее значение [font size="2"] ?

```
function getData() {


var url = "http://quantumonline.com/search.cfm?tickersymbol=AHL-D&sopt=symbol";
Logger.log(url);
var fromText = '<font size="2">';
var toText = '</font>';

var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
var scraped = Parser
                .data(content)
                .from(fromText)
                .to(toText)
                .build();



Logger.log(scraped);
  return scraped[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался почему не работала, данный скрипт использует .iterate(); для возврата данных массивом. итоговый код должен выглядеть так:

```
function getData() {


 var url = "http://quantumonline.com/search.cfm?tickersymbol=AHL-D&sopt=symbol";
 Logger.log(url);
 var fromText = '<font size="2">';
var toText = '</font>';

var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
var scraped = Parser
                .data(content)
                .from(fromText)
                .to(toText)
                .iterate();


Logger.log(scraped);
  return scraped[1];
}
```